# Rspec reuse code iterations between specs

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

We are working to set Rspect at work for test our application, and we run into this 'problem'.

We have some scenarios where the start of the spec is the same for all the 3 specs, and we want to share the common logic of the 3.

Example

This logic runs in 3 different specs

```
describe "#include?" do
  before(:all) do
    @user = "Logic here for create a new user"
  end

  context "repeat logic" do
    it "fake context that will be repeat on multiple specs" do
      fake.should be_true
    end
  end

  context "repeat logic 2" do
    it "fake context that will be repeat on multiple specs" do
      fake.should be_true
    end
  end
end
```

Now I want a way to include this little spec on each of the specs I need for don't repeat the same logic on 3 different specs.

We tested w shared examples, but looks like shared_examples and context don't runs the iterations, only can share functions and variables.

What is the correct way to include repeating logic in the specs

Comment: `shared_examples` seems the solution for you, but you said it doesn't work. Could you elaborate, what you meant to say by saying not working ?

Comment: When I add a shared_Examples to my other specs the logic inside Context "test" do is not executed.

Comment: [example here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/example-groups/shared-examples#shared-examples-group-included-in-two-groups-in-one-file) is telling it should work,, I don't know about yours.

Comment: Its possible to share_context between 2 difFerent files ?

Comment: Yes.. possible.. check their doco.. They mentioned it..

Comment: You say shared examples didn't work for you; include the code in your post, maybe someone can help.